# React class component : Why is it not causing a re-render?

Tags: reactjs

Why the code downbelow is not causing a re-render even though state is changed?

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 1
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    this.setState(previousState => {this.state.counter  = previousState.counter + 1},()=>{
      console.log(this.state.counter)
    });
  }
```

But this works... because i'm change this.state.counter??

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 1
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    this.setState(previousState => {this.state.counter  = previousState.counter + 1},()=>{
      console.log(this.state.counter)
    });
  }
```

I am aware of the shorter code:

```
handleClick = () =>{
   this.setState({counter : this.state.counter + 1})
}
```

Comment: I don't see a difference between the two code blocks. What do you mean?

Comment: In the first block, you aren't actually use Reacts `setState` to set the state, you are directly modifying it. (And the second block now, they seem to have been edited to match?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the state using:

```
this.setState(previousState => { this.state.counter = previousState.counter + 1 })
```

Will directly modify React state, which should be avoided and can lead to unexpected side effects (Like the component not re-rendering).

What you seem to be trying to do (Modify the state based on the previous state), should be done like this:

```
this.setState(previous => ({ counter: previous.counter + 1 }))
// Or
this.setState(previous => { return { counter: previous.counter + 1 } })
```

Which returns the change, so React can be aware of the change and handle it asynchronously, rather than modifying it yourself outside of Reacts control.

[Relevant React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Comment: this.state.counter or state.counter ?

Comment: last question : this.setState(*** Is here a hidden RETURN ***{counter : this.state.counter + 1})  like in es6 someFunc = (a,b) => a+b - @DBS

Comment: Exactly, the first of the two valid options returns automatically due to the `( )`, e.g. `a => (a)` where as the second has to explicitly return a value due to the `{ }`, e.g. `a => { return a }`

Comment: they gotta add more new brackets: squiggly, notation, round brackets aren't cutting it  xD

Answer (score 0):

you are updating direct state variable. Better return updated state on **immutable** way from `setState` callback like below

```
this.setState(previousState => {
      let counter  = previousState.counter + 1
      return {...previousState,counter}
    })
```

Comment: why do you need ...previousState ( line 3 )

Comment: may be you have any other state value. it will just copy on that